# How to dynamically choose the configurations based on the environment in JAVA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constants

I have a utility class which has common configurations related to email-sender, the configurations changes based on the environment like `Staging` and `Production`. Now how can I dynamically choose the configurations based on the environment?

here is my code,

**EmailUtility.java**

```
package com.housecar.common;

public class EmailUtility {

 //For staging 
 public static final String FROM_EMAIL_ID = "xx12@xyz.com";
 public static final String FROM_NAME = "xyz";
 static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "xx12@xyz.com";
 static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "15sss67$";
 public static final String REPLY_EMAIL_ID = "xx12@xyz.com";
 public static final String MAIL_SMTP_PORT = "587";
 public static final String MAIL_SMTP_SOCKET_FACTORY_PORT = "587";
 public static final String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
 public static final String MAIL_SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_CLASS = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";


 //for production

 /*public static final String FROM_EMAIL_ID = "admin@xyz.com";
 public static final String FROM_NAME = "xyz";
 static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "AKYeeeELEQAGAA"; // Replace with
                                                            // your SMTP
                                                            // username.
 static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "gvwwwwwbgpGm/C/LmUYUK5HosQar7mTSwjl5MFeBRR";
 public static final String REPLY_EMAIL_ID = "admin@xyz.com";
 public static final String MAIL_SMTP_PORT = "587";
 public static final String MAIL_SMTP_SOCKET_FACTORY_PORT = "587";
 public static final String SMTP_HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
 public static final String MAIL_SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_CLASS = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";*/

}
```

In my code I'm manually commenting out the configuration!

Comment: You should look into property files.

Comment: Have you not using any properties file or something like that. ??

Comment: what means dynamically? change config while running the app or just by any startup?

Comment: you can do a properties file, and then read it for your purpose for example for production `production.mail.smtp.port=587` and for staging `staging.mail.smtp.port=587`

Comment: Add properties to `application.properties` define them before you start depending on the evn.  Ex:  from.email.id = xx12@xyz.com and inject the property into your utility class.

Comment: use a `properties` file or a `yml` file to store this environment specific data

Comment: @lazarov can u please write the same briefly in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the properties file to solve your problem, like u can have two property files depending on the environment.

1) config_staging.properties
2) config_production.properties

and move your staging email configuration to  config_staging.properties, move your production configuration to  config_production.properties.

which will be configured while running the app.

for example,

config_staging.properties

```
 smtp.username = "xx12@xyz.com";
 smtp.password = "15sss67$";
```

config_production.properties

```
smtp.username = "AKYeeeELEQAGAA";
smtp.password = "gvwwwwwbgpGm/C/LmUYUK5HosQar7mTSwjl5MFeBRR";
```

then inject them into EmailUtility class,

```
@Value("${smtp.username}")
private String smtpUsername;


@Value("${smtp.password}")
private String smtpPassword;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should lookup the system dependend values from a properties store (e.g. a properties file which is handled by Javas `Properties` class).

But you should not provide all systems information in the same file.

You should have separate files (with the same name) an have your deployment process copying the file for the target system to the expected location.

This way you enable operations team to manipulate (or preconfigue) a properties file with data you (as a developer) should not know, eg. passwords for high security systems...

Answer (score 2):

Add the following into your `application.properties` file:

```
from.email.id = xx12@xyz.com
from.name = xyz

...
```

e.t.c

You define those properties before you start your application (depending on your evn in your case).
Of course you need to inject them into your class as follows:

```
@Value("${from.email.id}")
private String fromEmailId;
```

So now the `fromEmailId` will have the value given into the `application.properties` file.

Good luck.

EDIT:

If you want a little bit higher level of security you can use `jasypt` to cript your passwords into your `applicaiton.properties` file. At the end the password will look something like this:

```
smtp.password = ENC(5KZL2q+Ute21FzCsJy/h0aIp75TZgHBHx8L11R+jTJs0=)
```

Comment: You've got a typo in `application.properties` on the last line

Answer (score 1):

In spring you can set an external configuration with [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) or [yaml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties).

Otherwise, if you need to change configuration while running the app and you're using a database, you could create a configuration table in your db with key-value configs and read them in your code.

For example, a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE configuration (
    key varchar(255),
    value varchar(255)
);
```

Where `key` is the property name and `value` is the property value.

A property

```
environment=development
```

could become

```
INSERT INTO configuration (key, value) VALUES('environment', 'development');
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are a step in the right direction.

Some suggest to move the configuration values into a `.properties` file. This is a big step in the right direction, but ignores the fact that you're using Spring Boot.

Some suggest to move the configuration values into the Spring `application.properties` or `application.yaml` files. This is the better choice for a Spring application. `application.properties` is actually just a `.properties` file like first suggested, but is automatically loaded by the Spring Framework. This is all described in [Chapter 24. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) of the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/index.html).

But, your question actually said:

> [...] **common configurations** related to email-sender, the configurations changes based on the environment like Staging and Production.

Spring has a very nice feature, where you can have one set of configuration files (or even a single `.yaml` file), and the framework will automatically load the appropriate configuration values, depending on where the application is running, in Staging or Production. This is all described in [Chapter 25. Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

Answer (score 1):

`application-{profile}.properties` or `application-{profile}.yml` allows you to customize your application based on spring profile.

It is possible to create beans only in {profile} using:

```
@Service
@Profile(profile-name)
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceInterface {
}
```

Also it is possible to create beans based on properties values and conditions.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = EmailProperties.PREFIX, name = "fromId")
public BeanClass bean() {
    return new BeanClass(okHttpProperties.getFromId());
}
```

Conditional beans can be based on expression

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}'=='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'")
public DbUtil dbMysqlUtil() {
    ...
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}'=='org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver'")
public DbUtil dbHsqlUtil() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make configuration.properties file separate for stage and production. these configuration files will have corresponding properties. Now while Application startup you can first read Properties based on environment. environment value you can pass as argument in your application. You just need to write a simple `ConfigurtionReader` class which will read required configuration before application startup. Below is the code sample considering a very simple property file reading in plain java.

This will read a property file which is placed parallel to jar(current application).

```
public class ConfigurationReader {

    /** The job config prop. */
    private static final Properties JOB_CONFIG_PROP = new Properties();

    /**
     * Function is used to read configuration file that is placed in same place
     * where project jar is located.
     * 
     */
    public void readConfiguration(final String jobName) {
        File jarPath;
        String propertiesPath = " ";
        String jobConfigFile = " ";
        try {
            jarPath = new File(ConfigurationReader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
            propertiesPath = jarPath.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
            jobConfigFile = propertiesPath + File.separator + AppConstants.CONFIGURATION_FOLDER_NAME
                    + File.separator + jobName + AppConstants.PROP;
            JOB_CONFIG_PROP.load(new FileInputStream(jobConfigFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNtFoundExep) {
            throw fileNtFoundExep;
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            throw iOException;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    public static String getPropertyValue(final String key) {
        return JOB_CONFIG_PROP.getProperty(key);
    }

    public static void setPropertyValue(final String key, final String value) {
        JOB_CONFIG_PROP.setProperty(key, value);
    }
}
```

You can then get/set the property value using...

```
ConfigurationReader.getPropertyValue("abc");
ConfigurationReader.setPropertyValue("abc","xyz");
```

This is just a simple approach to achieve the reading of properties from a property file. You can do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both methods :

1. specifying the active profile(eg. application-{profile}.properties) 
   This is fine and pretty straight forward. The build process will resolve the environment specific properties file. Files for each env can be maintained in source control. Prod properties file(not accessible to dev/qe) can be secured in source control. The downside is that managing the different properties can get out of sync(aka configuration drift) (eg. a certain property key was added in dev but not in qe)
2. specifying the custom argument in running the app (eg. -Dapp.home)
   You have to add code to customize the loading the of the properties file. Some customization can include handling of encrypted property values. Property key/values can be maintained in Chef (or equivalent tool). See sample code below:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class MyExternalConfig {

       @Bean
       public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer(){

           //this is an external file path
           String appHomeConfig = System.getProperty("app.home") + File.separatorChar + "config";

           PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
           final Resource extResource = new FileSystemResource( new File( appHomeConfig, "application.properties") );
           ppc.setLocations( new Resource[] { extResource } ); //add other properties file if needed
           ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
           return ppc;
       }
   }
   ```